# c# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when excel file its been created

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I created an object that create dynamic excel files.

This project was working perfectly but now throw an exception.

The process throw an exception when are adding a workbook.

Im doing this:

app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1)

The error: (edited)

[image]

Comment: Not knowing Spanish, this could be completely wrong, but have you tried the suggestions here?  http://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/mensaje-error-de-excel-2013/87a2697e-486f-4b69-a5ad-ff6913fe1cda?msgId=01fcbc4e-117e-4224-90a8-bcb6b12c784f

Comment: You should bear in mind that this is an English-speaking site and that most of people does not understand the error message you are showing (you should translate it). Without more information it is a bit difficult to know what is happening exactly (never seen this error before); but I guess that the first thing to do is checking whether there are too many opened Excel instances (what this error is complaining about). From your code (workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1)), it seems that you open files in a quite systematic, regular way, so it might easily be the case.

Comment: using cominterop to excel can be problematic with asp.net

Comment: But i was using it and worked fine. What could have happened?

Comment: Using Excel on a web server is a very, very bad idea.  It is a very heavy process, designed to run on a workstation.  You don't need many clients to connect to your server to make it fall over.

Answer (score 0):

try that.

```
workBook = app.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);    
workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```